# detecting features sensitive to patterns but not to shape

Tags: image, matlab, computer-vision, pattern-matching, surf

I am using SURF feature detector with MATLAB to detect and extract features within faces of monkey. Ovale faces have been cut out so that the background is all white. My problem is many (if not most) of the features described the periphery of the ovale, ie the shape of the cutout, not facial patterns. As a consequence, matching features between to faces lead to matched features that are exclusively peripheral.
What would you suggest (image preprocessing; modifying SURFT parameters, etc...) to force the algorithm detecting features within the face?
Thanks !!
[image]
[image]

Comment: What about just discarding the feature points at the periphery ?

Comment: yes but in practice to do this ? the ovale has not the same shape between images, so for each image I would need to identify features that caracterize a sharp change in contrast, from grey to pure white...

Comment: Finding the ellipse shouldn't be an issue, knowing that the background is pure white. A little bit of dilation will enlarge it so that the unwanted feature points can be masked out.